# How can you serve locally stored wsdl file from nginx

Tags: nginx, wsdl

I am trying to workout a solution which let's us serve a wsdl file stored locally from our nginx web server. The WSDL is accessed from the browser with URL in the format:

https://*******/nameofthewsdl?wsdl

I am trying to place a block in my vhost conf file like this:

```
 location ~ /******** {
        root /etc/nginx/docs/;
        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
```

Have placed the wsdl file under the location /etc/nginx/docs but it always give 404. Not sure how to progress this.

Comment: first of all is it really `nameofthewsdl?wsdl` or `.wsdl`? Second please share the location configuration as the location is important. If possible please share the access.log showing the 404 as well. In general, serving wsdl is not more then serving a static XML file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Serving static XML files via NGINX is not a big deal. Given all your wsdl-files are having the file ending wsdl this configuration should work.

```
location ~* \.(wsdl)$ {
   root /etc/nginx/docs/;
   default_type application/xml;
}
```